# How to avoid duplicate rows in JOIN?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two identical tables (one with data from 2000-2009 and the other with data 2000-2013), and I am comparing both tables by left Join old with new on ID column and getting many-to-many mapping.

Table Structure(both)

```
ID  Date  Result1  Result3  Result3 Result10
```

Expected result is

```
ID  new_Date Old_Date new_Result1 old_Result1 new_Result10  old_Result10
```

How can I avoid many to many relation?

```
ID  new_Date    Old_Date 
--  ----------  ----------
15  2005-05-04  2005-05-04 
15  2006-11-23  2005-05-04 
15  2005-05-04  2006-11-23 
15  2006-11-23  2006-11-23
```

EXPECTED

```
ID  new_Date    Old_Date 
--  ----------  ----------
15  2005-05-04  2005-05-04 
15  2006-11-23  2006-11-23
```

Comment: Please post your SQL

Comment: When the ID is unique in both tables, and you join by the ID, it shouldn't duplicate rows.

Comment: On which bases you are joining the tables? Are the IDs gonna be the `SAME` - and valid, if you are using `ID`?

Comment: is this the sort of thing you are looking for? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Comment: Hi Stefan, ID is same and also most of the date are same as well, only the new table contain latest dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a DISTINCT?
As in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name, lastName FROM Person
```

This will ensure unique results. Also you may consider doing a UNION on two queries as this also ensures uniqueness.
As in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name, lastName FROM Person
UNION    
SELECT DISTINCT id, name, lastName FROM Person2
```

Comment: Hi. I have done UNION on two table, It was so simple and coudn't think before! Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Date as new_Date, B.Date as Old_Date, (...)
FROM SomeTable1 as A
JOIN SomeTable2 as B ON A.ID=B.ID
```

Comment: SELECT o.ID, n.Date as new_Date, o.Date as Old_Date, (...)
FROM  oldTable  o
LEFT JOIN  newTable  nON o.ID=n.ID